# Jquery - Ajax - display submit button after loading image?

Tags: jquery, html

```
   $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/admin/"+urlPage+"?t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="+
                thumb_width+"&h="+thumb_height+"&x1="+x_axis+"&y1="+y_axis,
            cache:false,

            success:function(rsponse)
            {  
                $("#cropimage1").hide();
                $("#thumbs1").html("");
                if(th_size == '1'){
                $("#thumbs").html("<img src='<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/upload/temporary/thumb/"+rsponse+"?version="+Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)*10+"' /><input type='button' class='save-btn' onclick='refresh();' name='save' value='<?php echo Yii::t(Yii::app()->session["translator"], "Save and continue");?>'>");
               $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#thumbs').offset().top }, 'slow');
                document.getElementById("small_image").value =rsponse;
               //alert(document.getElementById("small_image").value)
                }

    }
```

Here am loading a div id "thumbs" dynamically on response from ajax call.Inside this thumbs div there is  an image and submit button .. The issue is that the submit button loads quickly but if the image is heavy its taking time to load. How can i make submit button  to load after image .. Any Help appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, I use jQuery throughout instead of mixing things

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/admin/"+urlPage+"?t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="+thumb_width+"&h="+thumb_height+"&x1="+x_axis+"&y1="+y_axis,
  cache:false,
  success:function(rsponse) {  
    $("#cropimage1").hide();
    $("#thumbs1").empty();
    if(th_size == '1'){
      $("#thumbs").html('<img id="thumbImage" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/upload/temporary/thumb/'+rsponse+'?version='+Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)*10+' />');
      $("#thumbImage").on("load",function() {
        $("#thumbs").append('<input id="saveBtn" type="button" class="save-btn" onclick="refresh();" name="save" value="<?php echo Yii::t(Yii::app()->session["translator"], 'Save and continue');?>">');
      });
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#thumbs').offset().top }, 'slow');
      $("#small_image").val(rsponse);
    }
  }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.onload`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp) of image object.

The code would be like below:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    $("#thumbs").append(img).append("<input type='button' class='save-btn' onclick='refresh();' name='save' value='<?php echo Yii::t(Yii::app()->session["translator"], "Save and continue");?>'>");
};
img.src = '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/upload/temporary/thumb/"+rsponse+"?version="+Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)*10+"';
```

I don't run this code, if any error please point it out because of the value which contains php code.

But setting `src` and `onload` is exactly used like this.

Here is a simple jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/U7nYb/2/

Comment: @mplungjan please look at my updated post, and check the jsfiddle.

Comment: you MUST set the src AFTER setting onload!!! http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jDdrP/

Comment: @mplungjan is that necessary? I really don't know, please teach me.

Comment: It works in your fiddle because there is very little code in the onload and the image is just appended. In most cases more is happening and you want the onload to run when the src statement is executed.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you, I will continue google it about why. And I update my post later.